# service start / stop / restart - no output

Tags: service, debian-jessie

I installed debian jessie. When I use a service-command like "service nginx restart" there is no output. 
Previously I was using debian wheezy and there was feedback like (I don't remember exactly):
[ ok ] nginx stopped
[ ok ] nginx started

How can I re-enable this output?

Comment: I searched about 20 minutes for this but it's quite hard to find a good search term for this issue :-/

Comment: I think Debian Jesse uses systemd. Could you try ```systemctl start nginx```?

Comment: This is normal. You now only get output if there is a problem.

Comment: @Istvan I tried `systemctl start nginx` but this seems to behave exactly like `service start nginx`(no output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to call the service directly: `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Comment: Last time i had a similar issue i found my problem  in my init script. You should check that out.